# C++ map vs unordered_map in multithreaded environments

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a piece of C++ code where we access/modify a `map` from multiple threads without locking leading to segmentation faults. Recently, I converted this `map` to `unordered_map` (not to fix the issue but for some other reason) and segmentation faults became more frequent.

Cannot figure out the reason for this. Is `unordered_map` more prone to multithreading issues then `map`?

Comment: You have to assume NO class is threadsafe unless explicitly stated to be threadsafe in its documentation. Changing from one non-threadsafe class to another non-threadsafe class, like you are doing, is NOT going to help you. Learn about [std::mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) AND [std::scoped_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock). And lock access to the classes when modifying or reading.  Note : when you need more performance, use reader/writer lock pattern using : [std::shared_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock)

Comment: `map` tends to be a tree with operations that typically affect `O(log n)` elements, so you have a roughly `(log n)/n` chance of multithreaded collision. `unordered_map` tends to be a hash table with operations that typically affect `O(load factor)` elements, which is a roughly `load factor / n` chance of multithreaded collision. But `unordered_map` occasionally has to affect `O(n)` elements (rehashing), and then you have a guaranteed multithreaded collision.

Comment: @RaymondChen Awesome! Thanks for the reply. Makes perfect sense. Please put this as answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are using it in a multithreaded environment without appropriate locking. The fact that `unordered_map` crashes more frequently than `map` is coincidence. You need appropriate locking for both.

I am not sure about Raymond's explanation where operations on `unordered_map` affects `O(load factor)` (typically `0.75`) elements whereas operations on `map` affect `O(log n)` elements (typically more like `12`). That would seem to give the opposite conclusion, where conflicts are more likely to occur with `map`. It could be related to rebalancing operations, since expanding a hashtable (`unordered_map`) requires creating a whole new table and putting every element in the correct place in the new table, while rebalancing a binary tree (`map`) is more likely to only affect a handful of nodes at a time. This is all speculation.

I don't know your company, but generally when reporting to company leadership, unless they are familiar with software, you could speak in general terms: there was a latent (i.e. hidden) defect in the system. This latent defect would sometimes cause crashes. A recent change interacted with this in a way that increased the frequency of crashes. The latent defect is now fixed. Senior Engineering are more likely to want to know the technical details. Since you are reporting this to Leadership and Senior Engineering (and not just, say, entering it on a bug tracker), it seems that this was a major event and one or both teams will probably want to know how you plan to reduce the likelihood that similar defects occur in the future. If you are a junior engineer you probably won't have the final word on that but you can toss some ideas in.

Comment: (sometimes "appropriate locking" means "no locking" but your program does need locking)

Comment: I don't think it is a coincidence. I have seen it recently at three places. Chat GPT also says the same but I don't have a full faith in her explanation.

Comment: @Embydextrous Maybe your compiler's version of unordered_map is more prone to it. But maybe a different compiler's map is more prone to it. It doesn't matter and there is no reason you should care because you still need appropriate locking and that will fix both of them.

Comment: @Embydextrous you're basically asking why your Ford is more likely than your Honda to roll over when you drive it into a ditch. Who cares *why* one rolls over more than the other? Just don't drive your cars into ditches and then it doesn't matter.

Comment: Haha! Nice analogy. You are right. The issue is that Honda had been already in the ditch for last four years (I am new to the team and I discovered it few weeks back).

I did remove the ditch and replaced Honda with Ford but the fix was rollout for only 1% of users. So, there was an incident created. So trying to figure out why Ford did suffer more damage as a part of post-mortem report.

Comment: The problem goes away for sure. But the leadership team demands explanation for incidents. I don't think you got my last point. 

I am not looking for a fix. Still, I would need an explanation. So, to answer your question about who cares? Leadership team and Senior Engineering team who are part of incident review.

Also, if I have known this and I had to rollout a fix for 1% of users, I would have not converted map to unordered_map.

Comment: Also, I didn't waste much time. @raymondchen has given a nice and easy to understand explanation. Your answer does not answer my question. I am not asking why the segmentation fault is happening. I know the reason behind it.

I am asking why did it spike in case of unordered_map.

Comment: @Embydextrous I would estimate that Leadership does not care about data structures and Senior Engineering already sees that chasing the precise details here is a waste of time. For Leadership the report could say something like you had this bug (latent failure) where processor cores would sometimes interfere with each other and your change affected the memory access patterns which made this much more likely to manifest as a crash; you solved the underlying latent failure. Something like that. Yes, I like Raymond Chen's explanation although it's too technical for leadership.

Comment: @Embydextrous actually I think you would have to work out more detail to know whether Raymond's explanation fully explains the spike. In particular the load factor is often less than 1. How can touching 0.75 elements be more likely to cause a collision than touching log(n) (e.g. 12) elements? The real reason might lie in the rebalancing since rebalancing an unordered_map touches the whole table while a lot of the time map rebalancing only touches a few nodes.

Comment: I have checked earlier incidents and leadership and senior engineers team do care about a neat and concise explanation whether it involved data structures or not.

The explanation you mentioned - sometimes interfere with each other and affected memory access patterns - will be flagged for root cause.

Comment: I think you would have to work out more detail to know whether Raymond's explanation fully explains the spike.

Right. I would have to. But, I don't think it would be hard now.

Comment: @Embydextrous I added this to the answer

Comment: @Embydextrous -- Just don't use things that go beyond the "manufacturer's rating".  It is already well-known to C++ programmers (at least experienced ones) that no STL container is guaranteed to be thread-safe.  I don't understand why your company wants to be the crash dummy (deliberately use components that can break, breaks them, and want to know why), to be honest.

Comment: In the absence of rehashing, both `map` and `unordered_map` perform local accesses to a small number of elements, and the chance of conflict is low. But when an `unordered_map` rehashes, the entire `unordered_map` becomes unstable, and any concurrent access during the rehashing is a guaranteed conflict. So it's "map has a uniformly low risk of conflict. unordered map has a low risk of conflict most of the time, but a very high risk of conflict once in a while." It's that "very high risk of conflict once in a while" that is what's spiking the crashes.